# How to upload base64 / byte[] image to Azure Blob with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage

Here is my code IFormFile.

```
public static async Task<string> UploadFileToBlobStorage(IFormFile file)
        {
            string container = "abccontainer";
            string storageAccount_connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=abc/aXQUORlrTMNkxaUFPDDlLEW/mwe5Fihy+zl4p+ysF6Y+9JiMud8khH+AStEDb6DA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new(storageAccount_connectionString, container);

            BlobClient blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

            var mimeTypes = GetFileContentType(Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            var header = new BlobHttpHeaders
            {
                ContentType = mimeTypes
            };

            await blob.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), header);

            return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

But, I want to upload bytes[]  to blob storage.  Foe that, I will pass only byte[] array, and it should upload.

How can I do ?

```
public static async Task<string> UploadFileToBlobStorage(byte[] array)
        {
            return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`UploadAsync` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-uploadasync(system-binarydata-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) that takes a [`BinaryData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.binarydata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet) object.

You should be able to rewrite your code like this:

```cs
BlobClient blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("somename.txt"); // update as necessary

var header = new BlobHttpHeaders
{
    ContentType = "text/plain" // update as necessary
};


byte[] sourceData = getSourceData();
BinaryData uploadData = new BinaryData(sourceData);
await blob.UploadAsync(uploadData, new BlobUploadOptions { HttpHeaders = header });
```

Comment: But  BlobClient blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

blob.. this requires fileName... But I don't have.  So How can I ?

Comment: @GOPAL You're using `Path.GetFileName` which simply takes the last part of the string stored in `file.FileName` after the / or \. So "c:\mycomputer\bob\test.txt" would become "test.txt", etc. You're essentially asking me "what should I call my file once uploaded?" and I'm afraid that I can't tell you what to call the file on Azure's Blob Storage - you have to decide that. Perhaps talk to your coworkers or manager about what the file should be called once on Azure?

Comment: Assuming this has answered your question, don't forget to accept it. @GOPAL

Comment: `await blob.UploadAsync(uploadData, header);` - this method do not support two parameters `BinaryData` and `BlobHttpHeaders`. I think you should use `new BlobUploadOptions { HttpHeaders = header }` instead of `header`. (Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.14.0)